# Grails in Action 2nd Edition - Error Generating Scaffold

Tags: grails

I've been painstakingly trying to teach myself Grails using the Groovy Grails Tool Suite.

GGTS 3.6.4
Grails 2.4.4
JDK 1.8.0_45

I'm at P.92 in the book and have 2 problems:

1. When running the Grails console, I receive these errors:

   ```
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table post drop constraint FK_kpfnivid38f5bwx3yl1lxeeae if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "POST" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table post drop constraint FK_kpfnivid38f5bwx3yl1lxeeae if exists [42102-176]
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table post_tags drop constraint FK_rf0kr7eqk5xoalmc4gigdwg3p if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "POST_TAGS" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table post_tags drop constraint FK_rf0kr7eqk5xoalmc4gigdwg3p if exists [42102-176]
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table post_tags drop constraint FK_n8k2owli9ecanh4phj01mddvv if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "POST_TAGS" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table post_tags drop constraint FK_n8k2owli9ecanh4phj01mddvv if exists [42102-176]
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table profile drop constraint FK_c1dkiawnlj6uoe6fnlwd6j83j if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "PROFILE" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table profile drop constraint FK_c1dkiawnlj6uoe6fnlwd6j83j if exists [42102-176]
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table tag drop constraint FK_151ooxskkpn49blwsh7mjwysx if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "TAG" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table tag drop constraint FK_151ooxskkpn49blwsh7mjwysx if exists [42102-176]
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_user drop constraint FK_s7pwk9swjfqs0w7ub9tt5s47y if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "USER_USER" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table user_user drop constraint FK_s7pwk9swjfqs0w7ub9tt5s47y if exists [42102-176]
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_user drop constraint FK_1hl85r166108l1vgkxycm3cq0 if exists
   Error |
   2015-09-29 08:03:29,168 [main] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Table "USER_USER" not found; SQL statement:
   alter table user_user drop constraint FK_1hl85r166108l1vgkxycm3cq0 if exists [42102-176]
   ```

My guess is that the problem is because I've not changed my `DataSource.groovy` file to `'update'` instead of `'create-drop'` and bring the DB out of memory.

I haven't tested that theory because the Grails console still ran, which then led to my second error.

2. We're told to generate 4 controllers, using the following commands:

   ```
   create-scaffold-controller com.grailsinaction.User
   create-scaffold-controller com.grailsinaction.Profile
   create-scaffold-controller com.grailsinaction.Post
   create-scaffold-controller com.grailsinaction.Tag
   ```

Each time, I receive an "EOF expected" error:

```
1 compilation error:

expecting EOF, found 'com' at line: 1, column: 28
```

These two errors don't seem related, and rather than just skip it, I'd really like to understand what's going on...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the very long paragraphs of 'gobblygook.' I'm still new to SO and don't know how to get that properly formatted ...

Answer (score 0):

`DataSource.groovy` file to `'update'` instead of `'create-drop'` and bring the DB out of memory.

This is assuming you have configured your data source to connect to a real database.

I can see hbm2ddl is the logs above and for your internal in memory DB it should really should be `'create-drop'`

`DataSource.groovy` file to `'update'` tells your application to only update existing tables, this will not create any new tables.

In the case of a real life application that connects to lets say MySQL. This setting would equate to you then also manually updating the database and creating any new tables that you have designed in development.

`DataSource.groovy` file to `'create-drop'` is as the name states, it will create new tables and drop entries, so in the case of development environment and even some other environments such as test you may be happy to leave it on create-drop and let grails generate the tables.

The only 1 thing to watch for is if you have lets assume you have some domain class that has a

```
Boolean isValid

static constraints { 
 isValid(nullable:false)
}
```

If you later decide no actually it should be nullable in the case of the MySQL example, you would have to log into it and manually tweak it since its already created. in the case of inline memory (your example) who cares next run-app =  fresh db .

In regards to :

`create-scaffold-controller`

This is a new one, http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Command%20Line/create-scaffold-controller.html It looks correct, what you are executing.

But to try to simplify or expand the horizon, if I understand correctly (I haven't started to delve into what that command does), but surely can't be far off of doing something like this manually.

`grails create-controller com.grailsinaction.User`

Then going to the user class and doing:

```
class UserController {
  static scaffold = true   
}
```

Save repeat for each one and then continue with the docs..

Learn more about the concept of scaffolding here:

http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-scaffolding/

http://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/07/19/grails-scaffolding-controllers-and-views/

Also if you are using ggts go over the domain class with your right mouse button choose I think grails generate controllers and views

This will be the alternative to scaffolding which is what scaffolding gives you dynamically is then generated for you to use and edit. Its a good way it get into grails since it gives you stuff you can see/edit and learn from.

Scaffolding just hides all of that and is tidy way of hiding the generated stuff.